# Get the owner of the file from ContentVersion? - How to Merge 2 queries

Tags: query, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am querying for some data on a contentversion record, and also need to get the ContentDocumentId owner.

I have these 2 queries, that work.

But, is there a way I can do it in a single query?

Query 1 - Get the File name and version

```
[Select ID, PathOnClient, VersionData from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId  = :ContentDocumentId limit 1];
```

Query 2 - Get the owner id

```
[Select id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.ownerid from ContentDocumentLink where contentdocumentid = :ContentDocumentId limit 1];
```

I am sure that there's a way, just can't figure how....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `ContentDocumentLink` at all. Just traverse the relationship from `ContentVersion`.

```
SELECT ID, PathOnClient, VersionData, ContentDocument.OwnerId 
FROM ContentVersion 
WHERE ContentDocumentId  = :ContentDocumentId 
LIMIT 1
```

Note that you may want to add additional filters if, for example, you want the *latest* version of any given document.

Comment: Thanks. no need for filter. when this query runs, there's only 1 version. thanks.